# How many even digit integers inside of an array (Python)

Tags: python

Inside an array there are integers, each integer has either odd number of digits or even number of digits.

My output: Goes through each element in array and prints if Individually, even number or odd number of digits -

1

1

Expected output: Gets total number of even digit integers inside array -

2

```
exampl=[22,234,2463]

def findEven(f):
    countz=0
    LengthOfInt=len(str(f))
    if(LengthOfInt%2)==0:  #if it is even, add 1 to count
        countz+=1
        print(countz)

for i in exampl:
    findEven(i)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you want to pass the arrays into the Function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exampl=[22,234,2463]

def findEven(f):
    return len(str(f))%2==0
count=0

for i in exampl:
    if findEven(i)==True:
        count+=1 
print(count)
```

## OR

```
exampl=[22,234,2463]

def findEven(f):
    count=0
    for i in f:
        if len(str(i))%2==0:
            count+=1
    return count

print(findEven(exampl))
```

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```
exampl=[22,234,2463]
```

Solution:

```
l = [x for x in exampl if x%2 == 0]
len(l)
```

Answer:

```
l
Out[23]: [22, 234]

len(l)
Out[24]: 2
```

Explanation:

We are taking all the numbers from the list `exampl` in the list `l` if they are divisible by two, and then just seeing the `len()` of `l` will give us the count.

Comment: The most pythonic answer of the lot.

Comment: Thanks @sotmot! Hope this helps someone understand!

Answer (score 1):

What's going on here is that your variable `countz` is scoped to be inside the `findEven` function. It gets set to `0` each time the function runs. Furthermore, the `print` function runs every time you have an even-digit number.

What you want to do instead, is to make a function that *returns* a boolean - whether the number has an even number of digits or not. Then you can count the `True` or `False` values.

```py
example = [22, 234, 2463]

def is_even(value):
    length = len(str(value))
    return length % 2 == 0

count = 0
for i in example:
    if is_even(i):
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
sum(len(str(x))%2==0 for x in exampl)
```

Comment: with this, the output gets printed i times? i placed this line after the if statement

Comment: @VoidS It just gives you the output, an integer 2.

Answer (score 1):

This answer stays as close as possible to the code written in the original post.

1. You `for` loop should be inside of `findEven()`, so that you can find all the even numbers from within that one function.
2. Your `findEven()` function should `return countz` instead of `print(countz)`, and that line should be indented by one less tab.

The following code is very close to the original, but it should accomplish what you want.

```
exampl = [22,234,2463]

def findEven(f):
    countz = 0
    for i in f:
        LengthOfInt = len(str(i))
        if LengthOfInt % 2 == 0:  #if it is even, add 1 to count
            countz += 1
    return countz

print(findEven(exampl))
```

Comment: thanks this is accurate. however can you please explain the return countz? can we leave this part out? or replace with print?

Comment: The purpose of a function is to give you an answer. If you `print`, then the answer will just be displayed on the screen. Instead, if you `return`, then the answer will be substituted into the place where you called the function, which is much more useful in general.So when you call `print(findEven(exampl))`, the `findEven(exampl)` part gets changed into the number `countz` that you `return`ed.